# jquery select multiple while traversing DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I am trying to select all elements with the "findme" class, and from those get the selects that are nearby them. 
http://jsfiddle.net/R93md/1/

Specifically I have tried

```
$(".findme").parent().prev().first();
```

then once I have all selects I plan on doing a

```
.each(function (){doSomething(this);})
```

to each select. I am stuck getting the selects because it seems that I am never going down and retrieving the contents of the span.

Comment: I think there is also `.closest()`. The name sounds promising if you want to get elements nearby..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".findme").closest("td").find("select").each(function() { 
    doSomething(this); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first grab the parent `<td>` element and then use `find()` like so

```
$('.findme').parents('td').find('select').each(function(){
    ...
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JYGK3/

Edit:
In review of the other answers here, I've concluded that you probably should use `closest()` rather than `parents()`.  If the table is nested, it could produce unwanted results.

http://jsfiddle.net/JYGK3/1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.closest()` to go up to the common `<td>` and then `.find()` to go down from there to find the neighboring `<select>`:

```
$(".findme").each(function() {
    var select = $(this).closest("td").find("select");
    // now do what you want to with the neighboring select object
    // here you have access to both this which is the findme object
    // and select which is the select object
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should follow this:

```
$('.findme').each(function(){
    var el = $(this).closest('td').find('select');
    dosomething(el);
});
```